# Core functioning of Expression templates: assignment operator sub-template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm sorry if the title sounds confusing but the problem is. I am studying a very minimalist case of [Expression Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) (see full C++98 code below) and I understand everything except one detail: why the assignment operator of the Vector type needs to have a foreign or third-party template A in order to work? See the annotated line below (sorry don't find a way to have line numbers)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class A>
struct Expr {
    inline operator const A&() const {
        return *static_cast<const A*>(this);
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------
// Addition Expression
// ----------------------------------------------
template<class A, class B>
class DExprSum : public Expr< DExprSum< A,B > > {
    const A& a_;
    const B& b_;

public:
    DExprSum(const A& a, const B& b) : a_(a), b_(b) { }

    double operator()(int i) const {
        return (double)(a_[i] + b_[i]);
    }

    double operator[](int i) const {
        return this->operator()(i);
    }
};

template <class A, class B>
inline DExprSum<A, B> operator+(const Expr<A>& a, const Expr<B>& b) {
    return DExprSum<A, B>(a, b);
};

// ----------------------------------------------
// A simple vector class
// ----------------------------------------------
template<class T>
class Vector : public Expr<Vector<T> > {

private:
    T *p;
    int len;

public:
    Vector(int length) {
        len = length;
        p = new T[length];
    };

    T operator()(int i) const {
        return p[i];
    }

    T& operator[](int i) const {
        return p[i];
    }

    // <<<<<<------------ HERE why do I need a new template<class A>
    // rather than simply using Expr<Vector<T> > 
    template<class A>
    void operator=(const Expr<A>& expr) {
        const A& a(expr);

        // parallelize using OpenMP
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime) // OMP_SCHEDULE=static,50 OMP_NUM_THREADS=10
        for (int i=0; i < len; ++i) {
            p[i] = a(i);
        }
    }

    ~Vector() {
        delete[] p;
    };
};

int main() {
    Vector<double> a(3);
    Vector<double> b(3);
    Vector<double> c(3);

    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;

    b[0] = 2;
    b[1] = 3;
    b[2] = 4;

    c = a + a + b + b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            cout << c[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the assignment operator definition to (which is what it is actually intended):

```
void operator=(const Expr<Vector<T> >& expr) {
    const Vector<T>& a(expr);

    // parallelize using OpenMP
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime) // OMP_SCHEDULE=static,50 OMP_NUM_THREADS=10
    for (int i=0; i < len; ++i) {
        p[i] = a(i);
    }
}
```

I get the compiler error `error: no viable overloaded '='`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the argument passed to `Vector<T>::operator=` is not `Expr<Vector<T>>` (especially for the case using expression templates).

For `c = a + a + b + b;`, you're calling `operator+()` three times, the operations and arguments are saved in the expression template. The return value of `a + a + b + b` would be

```
DExprSum<DExprSum<DExprSum<Vector<double>, Vector<double>>, Vector<double>>, Vector<double>>
```

which could be cast to

```
Expr<DExprSum<DExprSum<DExprSum<Vector<double>, Vector<double>>, Vector<double>>, Vector<double>>>
```

and then parsed template argument `A` as

```
DExprSum<DExprSum<DExprSum<Vector<double>, Vector<double>>, Vector<double>>, Vector<double>>`
```

but it can't be cast to `Expr<Vector<double>>`.

**EDIT**

For the additional question,

`operator=` is a template function here. And no need to specify the template argument because of [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) when calling a template function.

Comment: Thanks, indeed! To make the answer complete could you please elaborate why `template A` is defined in the assignment operator but never declared anywhere when the assignment operator is used?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua First, `operator=` is a template function here. And no need to specify the template argument because of [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) when calling a template function.

Comment: Thank you again! if you could add that bit to the answer would be very nice and complete :)

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Fine, added.